# Community Evangelism Team - Skeptics in the Pub

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

StackExchange is hiring a [Community Evangelism Team](http://stackexchange.theresumator.com/apply/5bbnOo/Community-Evangelism-Team.html) and it is up to the community to decide what help they need.

*[(Listen to Podcast #6 for more detail discussion)](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/se-podcast-06/)*

I (as many of you are also) a member of my local skpetical group ([Bristol Skeptics](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/se-podcast-06/)). There are many of these regional groups around the world all (very) loosely affiliated.

I suggest the CET reach out to these groups initially for promotion; stickers, t-shirts etc. Eventually sponsorship or events could be considered.

I have a list of contacts for all **UK SitP** groups, I'm sure we have users with similar contacts in US, Australia and Europe.

Answer (score 5):

It's a joke, no, isn't it?

#### Evangelism.

For a skeptics site. :) I guess it was inspired by the holy ghost! :)

Answer (score 2):

We have a SitP group in Manchester (New Hampshire, yeah, stole all those UK names).

http://granitestateskeptics.org

Comment: Aren't you going to TAM?  That would be a great place to promote the site.